# Installing php* with mysql-server conflict

Tags: php, mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, apache

I am a Linux newb, trying to install php5 and httpd into my amazon ec2 linux instance with: yum -y install php* httpd;

I got hit with the following conflicts:

```
---> Package unixODBC.i686 0:2.2.14-11.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ghostscript.i686 0:8.70-11.20.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: urw-fonts >= 1.1 for package: ghostscript-8.70-11.20.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcupsimage.so.2 for package: ghostscript-8.70-11.20.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libjasper.so.1 for package: ghostscript-8.70-11.20.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcairo.so.2 for package: ghostscript-8.70-11.20.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcups.so.2 for package: ghostscript-8.70-11.20.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: ghostscript-fonts for package: ghostscript-8.70-11.20.amzn1.i686
---> Package gnutls.i686 0:2.8.5-4.6.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtasn1.so.3 for package: gnutls-2.8.5-4.6.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libtasn1.so.3(LIBTASN1_0_3) for package: gnutls-2.8.5-4.6.amzn1.i686
---> Package lcms-libs.i686 0:1.19-1.5.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libXt.i686 0:1.0.7-1.6.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libgomp.i686 0:4.6.2-1.27.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libtiff.i686 0:3.9.4-6.10.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libwmf-lite.i686 0:0.2.8.4-22.7.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cairo.i686 0:1.8.8-3.1.4.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpixman-1.so.0 for package: cairo-1.8.8-3.1.4.amzn1.i686
---> Package cups-libs.i686 1:1.4.2-44.10.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-common.so.3 for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-44.10.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-client.so.3 for package: 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-44.10.amzn1.i686
---> Package ghostscript-fonts.noarch 0:5.50-23.1.6.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-font-utils for package: ghostscript-fonts-5.50-23.1.6.amzn1.noarch
---> Package jasper-libs.i686 0:1.900.1-15.5.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libtasn1.i686 0:2.3-3.4.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package urw-fonts.noarch 0:2.4-10.7.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package avahi-libs.i686 0:0.6.25-11.12.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package pixman.i686 0:0.18.4-1.5.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-font-utils.i686 1:7.2-11.5.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXfont.so.1 for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.2-11.5.amzn1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfontenc.so.1 for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.2-11.5.amzn1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXfont.i686 0:1.4.1-2.6.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package libfontenc.i686 0:1.0.5-2.6.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php-mysql-5.3.14-2.21.amzn1.i686 conflicts php-mysqlnd
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php-mysql conflicts with php-mysqlnd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have previously installed mysql-server, and the version is 5.5.24.

Please advice on how to get over this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Good news is, you already have php installed! If it's not working, check config. Bad news is your problem not a mysql server problem it's a php one, as far as I know libmysql is conflicting with mysqlnd (which means php is installed but running an old driver). You don't really need to upgrade unless your web application is already using mysqlnd dependent functions, for example `$stmt->get_result();`.